# How to Install the GD Image Library for Wordpress?

Tags: php, c, wordpress, gd

Do you know how can I install `GD Library` for use it in `PHP files` of a `Wordpress` website?

I'm creating my own captcha and I need this library to create my different images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GD Library will need to be installed on the server that is hosting your website. This is not something that you can simply install in WordPress. The installation will depend on your server configuration and if you have access to do this.

If you do not maintain your server, then you should reach out to your host for help with this issue.

If you do manage your own server, you can install this yourself. Here are the commands that you would use to install the GD Library on an Ubuntu server that is running PHP 7. If your server is set up differently or running a different version of PHP then you would need to find the proper instructions.

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install php7.0-gd php7.0
```

Here are some further instructions: https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-php7-gd-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Before doing this, check your PHP version `php -v` and then try (say) `apt-get install php7.3-gd`. Note you should be logged in as root on the machine to do this. Check it's installed with `php -i | grep gd`. Then you will need to run `service apache2 restart` afterwards

Comment: In the newest version of Wordpress make sure have at least php7.4-gd installed. I had the latest (php8.x-gd), but Wordpress doesn't recognize it.